# Dilworth's Theorem for Totally Ordered Sets

Tags: order-theory

Dilworth's Theorem, states that in a poset the size of the largest antichain is the same size as the smallest chain decomposition. If I am understanding this correctly then, In a totally ordered set, there are no antichains. So the biggest antichain would be of size $0$ and therefore, the smallest chain decomposition would be of size $0$. This seems like a contradictory conclusion to me, so is there some sort of exceptions for posets with no antichains?

Comment: Any singleton is an antichain of size 1. In a totally ordered set there are no antichains except for these trivial ones.

Comment: Thank you for the clarification! I figured it was some kind of technicality I was missing.

Comment: You can check more generally what Dilworth's theorem says for a disjoint union of chains as an additional exercise.

Comment: @Karl: That seems like an answer to me?